# roundabout slider with iframe video javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have extracted a roundabout slider from this location `http://www.joezimjs.com/demos/roundabout-demo/`. I have used iframe videos instead of images. If i use video the round about slider not working properly that is if i click the video it started playing instead of scrolling. I need both the actions that is scrolling with playing on click the video.

Please refer the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/6rA32/1/`

Is there any possibility? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's possible.

Just wrap the iframe in a relative positioned div, put a 'layer' div alongside it, make it the same width and height as the iframe; absolute positioned. Make sure it has higher z-index than the iframe.

You can use classes that already added by roundabout to hide and show the 'layer' div. So when the video is not in focus, all you click is the 'layer', not the iframe.

Should work but untested though.